# Noexcept promise on derived class constructor: can that be used without promising noexcept on base constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

Let's say I have a class

```
class C : public B {
  public:
    C() noexcept;
}
```

Does the `noexcept` specifier require the same promise by the base class? That is, when I am considering using noexcept, do I just look at the behavior of C::C() or do I also need to consider whether B::B() may throw exceptions?

For example, if B::B throws an exception, does that propagate to C::C or to the code that was asking for a new class instance? -- If propagating to C::C, that would be one reason to avoid noexcept for the constructor if a base class is not noexcept for the constructor.

Comment: Can derived class construction succeed if baseclass construction failed?

Comment: No. So, when the compiler puts this all together, does it handle each constructor independently, meaning that a noexcept specification on a derived class has no effect on how the compiler manages the base constructor?

Comment: Actually, I think my question might have been misleading. If your baseclass is `vector` and you pass it a zero size, you can actually guarantee that no exception is throws. Similarly, `noexcept` means that something must not throw, lest `abort()` (I think, please refer to the docs) is invoked. So, if the base constructor isn't already `noexcept`, it must be wrapped in `try` - `catch`, but it can fulfill the `noexcept` guarantee.

Comment: I guess a better way of asking my question is: where does the exception go next? If the base class constructor throws an exception, does that then go to the derived class constructor or to the code that invoked the constructor?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt If the base class constructor throws it's actually not possible for a derived class constructor to 'swallow' that exception: either the derived constructor must throw or the program must terminate.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec says: "If a search for a matching exception handler leaves a function marked noexcept or noexcept(true), std::terminate is called immediately." If the baseclass throws and the derived class doesn't swallow the exception (which doesn't make sense) and it then propagates to the caller, it crosses the `noexcept` boundary and thus `terminate()` is called (not `abort()` as I wrote above).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is technically<sup>†</sup> no requirement for the base class constructor to be declared noexcept, but it must not throw, when called by a derived constructor that is declared noexcept.

So yes, you do need to consider whether the base class constructor may throw (exceptions or otherwise).

> I guess a better way of asking my question is: where does the exception go next?

The calls flow like this:

```
caller
  -> derived constructor (the noexcept applies to this)
    -> subobject constructors (includes bases)
    - derived constructor body (not a call, but part of the derived constructor that is executed after the subobjects are constructed)
```

So, if a subobject (whether it be a base or a member) constructor throws, it first goes to the derived constructor, which doesn't and can't<sup>††</sup> swallow the exception so it would propagate to the caller, if the constructor wasn't noexcept. But since it is, `std::terminate` gets called.

<sup>†</sup>If the base doesn't indeed throw as required by the derived, then it does meet the requirement and can itself be declared noexcept so there is rarly reason not to do so. Perhaps, if the base class is part of a library that must support c++03, while the derived class may assume a later standard, it would make sense.

<sup>††</sup>It can catch with a function-try-block, but those will always throw again.

Comment: You could use a function-try-block on `C`'s ctor to produce a nice error message (although it must go on to abort program, there's no way to recover)

Comment: @M.M oh yea, I forgot about those. I added a note to my answer.